# How to use WebRtc when NAT traversal doesn't seem to work?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to deploy a webrtc media server on kubernetes. The network is private, but it consists of 2 sub-networks - one for the kubernetes cloud and one for the clients. Therefore I need a stun server on the kubernetes cloud so that the client can get its external ip and port. However, udp packets sent from the pod to this ip and port do not reach the client.
It seems that another gateway is used in order to send packets from the pod to the client.

Is there a solution that can overcome this problem? Is there another way by which the client can discover its ip or by which the media server can discover the client's ip?

Everything works when I disable the "anonymize local ips" flag in chrome, but this solution is ugly...

Answer (score 1):

If the STUN server is running behind a publicly exposed IP/port pair, then it should be able to reach any clients. You should either run the STUN server with hostNetworking enabled or use a LoadBalancer service that makes the STUN server running with cluster IP accessible by the client (just like here: https://github.com/l7mp/stunner). Does this answer your question?

If you already have your STUN server exposed, and packets still do not reach the client, you probably face a firewall issue somewhere between the k8s cluster and the client I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understood.... I need to send audio from the server to the client. I can do it if I know the client's private IP. How will running with host networking enable help me if the host is on a different subnet and I don't know the client 's IP?

Comment: @Gregory oh, it is the media server pod -> external client IP path that does not work. My understanding was that the STUN server cannot reach the client. I guess there is a firewall along the path between the server and the client. In this case you can use a TURN server to relay media. For instance the above link consists a STUN and TURN server in a single pod, but you can use other solutions like co-turn.